# Azure function 3 to 4 upgrade error: Error configuring services in an external startup class

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I receiving the following error during the start-up procedure of my updated function apps.

> AZFD0005 Diagnostic event Error code AZFD0005 Level Error Message
> Error configuring services in an external startup class. Details
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExternalStartupException : Error
> configuring services in an external startup class. --->
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file
> specified. at
> SkyNav.API.Extensions.RegisterServices.AddCustomServices(IServiceCollection
> services) at
> /Users/mrogers/_AzureDevOps/SkyNavAPI/src/SkyNav.API/Extensions/RegisterServices.cs
> : 87 at SkyNav.API.Helpers.Startup.Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
> at
> /Users/mrogers/*AzureDevOps/SkyNavAPI/src/SkyNav.API/Helpers/Startup.cs
> : 15 at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.ConfigureStartup(IWebJobsStartup
> startup,WebJobsBuilderContext context,IWebJobsBuilder builder) at
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs
> : 166 at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.ConfigureAndLogUserConfiguredServices(IWebJobsStartup
> startup,WebJobsBuilderContext context,IWebJobsBuilder
> builder,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) at
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs
> : 130 at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.UseWebJobsStartup(IWebJobsBuilder
> builder,Type startupType,WebJobsBuilderContext context,ILoggerFactory
> loggerFactory) at
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs
> : 115 at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.UseExternalStartup(IWebJobsBuilder
> builder,IWebJobsStartupTypeLocator
> startupTypeLocator,WebJobsBuilderContext context,ILoggerFactory
> loggerFactory) at
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs
> : 213 at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__1(HostBuilderContext
> context,IWebJobsBuilder webJobsBuilder) at
> /*/src/WebJobs.Script/ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs : 226 End of
> inner exception

Here's the csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
 
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Newtonsoft.Json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="11.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Auth" Version="1.62.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.2.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.28.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="6.0.21" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="11.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SkyNav.Core\SkyNav.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here's the Startup.cs code

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using xxxxxx.API.Extensions;
using xxxxxx.API.Helpers;
using xxxxxx.API.Mappers;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace xxxxxx.API.Helpers
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddCustomServices();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code the add the customservices

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using xxxxxx.API.Entities;
using xxxxxx.API.Interfaces;
using xxxxxx.API.Mappers;
using xxxxxx.API.Services;
using xxxxxx.Core.Identity;
using xxxxxx.Core.Repository;

namespace xxxxxx.API.Extensions
{
    public static class RegisterServices
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddCustomServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            #region Service
            services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>));

            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizedService, AuthorizedService>();

            services.AddScoped<ITourService, TourService>();

            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

            services.AddScoped<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();

            services.AddScoped<IBlobService, BlobService>();

            services.AddScoped<ILogService, LogService>();

            services.AddScoped<ISceneService, SceneService>();

            services.AddScoped<IMediaService, MediaService>();

            services.AddScoped<IHotspotService, HotspotService>();

            services.AddScoped<IExportJsonService, ExportJsonService>();

            services.AddScoped<IIconsService, IconsService>();

            services.AddScoped<ITourModifiedService, TourModifiedService>();

            services.AddScoped<IIndexService, IndexService>();

            services.AddScoped<ICustomerPermissionService, CustomerPermissionService>();

            services.AddScoped<IAuditService, AuditService>();

            services.AddScoped<ITourGroupService, TourGroupService>();

            services.AddScoped<IMediaGroupService, MediaGroupService>();

            services.AddScoped<ISceneVariantService, SceneVariantService>();

            services.AddScoped<IMailService, MailService>();

            services.AddHttpClient();

            services.AddScoped(typeof(IPasswordHasher<User>), typeof(PasswordHasher<>));

            #endregion

            #region Mapper
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(UserMapper).Assembly);

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(CustomerMapper).Assembly);

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ImageMapper).Assembly);

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(LogMapper).Assembly);

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(TourMapper).Assembly);

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(SceneMapper).Assembly);

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MediaMapper).Assembly);

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(HotspotMapper).Assembly);

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(TourGroupMapper).Assembly);

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MediaGroupMapper).Assembly);

            #endregion

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked all direct dependencies and transitive dependencies and from what I can work out there's no dependency on Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core version 7.0.0.

Also the target framework for the project is .net6.0 Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core 7.0.0 shouldn't be required nor linked to.

Comment: Could you please share your `Startup` or `Program.cs` file.

Comment: Also, why is an Azure function app trying to reference files on my local directory ?

/Users/mrogers/_AzureDevOps/SkyNavAPI/src/SkyNav.API/Extensions/RegisterServices.cs : 87 at SkyNav.API.Helpers.Startup.Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder) at /Users/mrogers/AzureDevOps/SkyNavAPI/src/SkyNav.API/Helpers/Startup.cs :

Answer (score 0):

***To resolve the error, Install `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core` version `6.0.0`:***

[image]

I tried with `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core` version `7.0.0` in my `.NET 6.0` with `V4 Functions Runtime`, it was leading to some errors. I had to switch to `6.0.0` version and it got resolved.

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[image]